# Send Tweet with Emoji TweetSharp

Tags: vb.net, twitter, tweetsharp

I am using TweetSharp to send tweets with vb.net

I can send text tweet from code,there is no problem.

But i want to send text with emoji .

I have checked google but there isn't example.

For example i want to use this emoji with my text

```
Dim oOptions As New TweetSharp.SendTweetOptions
oOptions.Status = " Hello Twitter "
Dim Status As TweetSharp.TwitterStatus = Nothing
Status = TW.SendTweet(oOptions)
```

When i try to send this; its look like ; 
�� Hello Twitter ��

How can i write text with emoji?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: When i try to send this; İts look like ;
�� Hello Twitter ��

Comment: You need to use the hex equivalent of the emoji.

Comment: But how?
What is the hex equ. of this emoji?
when i convert ascii , it is 63  =�

i found this emojies character set utf8mb4.
but vb.net not support or i dont know how to convert

Comment: i think i found hex equivalent :1f4fa
ok but how can i write :)

https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f4fa.png

Comment: This is probably a bug in TweetSharp.